# Grepping Logs for output between different elements on Linux

Tags: linux, grep

How would I go about repeatedly searching through a file, starting at one piece of text and ending at another?

For example, I have a very large log. There are sections throughout the log that start and end with certain text, for example:

> ```
> [startset]
> blah blah blah
> [/startset]
> ```

I want to just gather the text inbetween [startset] and [/startset]. This section is reoccurring, so I need to loop through and continue doing this until all the text has been gathered (and dumped into a separate file)

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wouldn't be able to do it in grep.  Are you okay with perl scripting? That to me would be easiest.  Assuming your files stick to that format, here is a basic script with little error checking.

**My data file**

```
testlinux:~ # cat sample.txt
ignore
ignore
[startset]
grab this 1
grab this 2
[/startset]
ignore
ignore
[startset]
grab this 3
grab this 4
[/startset]
ignore this
ignore that
testlinux:~ #
```

**My perl script**

```
testlinux:~ # cat sample.pl
#!/usr/bin/perl

$infile="sample.txt";

open(INFILE,"$infile");

$startset=0;

while (<INFILE>) {
    chop($line=$_);
    if ($line =~ /\[startset\]/) {
            $startset=1;
            chop($line=<INFILE>);
    }
    if ($line =~ /\[\/startset\]/) {
            $startset=0;
    }
    if ($startset eq 1) {
            print "$line\n";
    }
}


testlinux:~ #
```

**Sample run:**

```
testlinux:~ # ./sample.pl
grab this 1
grab this 2
grab this 3
grab this 4
testlinux:~ #
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `awk`.  This use data from Bens post:

```
awk '/\[\/startset\]/ {f=0} f; /\[startset\]/ {f=1}' file
grab this 1
grab this 2
grab this 3
grab this 4
```

In general

```
awk '/stop/ {f=0} f; /start/ {f=1}'
```

Using the flag `f` to control the output if condition is met.